Running Multiple Tests with SQLX (Postgres) - Too Many Client Connections Error
I have a bunch of unit tests (about 200) that interact with a sqlx Postgres database. They are of the form shown in the code below.
#[tokio::test]
#[serial]
async fn insert_entity() {
    // Create a new connection to the database and return a DBConnection and User
    let (db, user) = test_setup_db_with_user().await

    // Truncate the DB to clear the tables before each test
    truncate_db_tables(&db).await;

    // Test logic here e.g. inserting an item to the DB
    let entity = create_dummy_entity(user.id);
    let result = Entity::db_insert(&db, &user.id, entity.clone())
        .await
        .unwrap();

    assert_eq!(result, entity);

    // Closing the pool and awaiting
    db.pool.pool.close().await;
}

The Problem
When I run these tests in serial, when I get to test ~60 or so depending on DB connection parameters such as:
TEST_POSTGRES_POOL_MAX_LIFETIME=1800
TEST_POSTGRES_POOL_IDLE_TIMEOUT=600
TEST_POSTGRES_POOL_MIN_CONNECTIONS=0
TEST_POSTGRES_POOL_MAX_CONNECTIONS=7
TEST_POSTGRES_POOL_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60

The DB becomes overwhelmed leading to the following error:
called \Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SQLX(Database(PgDatabaseError { severity: Fatal, code: "53300", message: "sorry, too many clients already",`

I've played around with the connection params e.g. setting MAX_CONNECTIONS to 100 (which just slowed down test execution) or increasing MIN_CONNECTIONS as well as the CONNECT_TIMEOUT etc to no avail. I've also tried running tests using cargo test -- --test-threads=1 incase there were multiple threads running.
Question(s)
How would I prevent the too many clients error. Am I properly closing the connections by calling db.pool.pool.close().await;, it doesnt seem like it
Is there a way to initialize the DB connection only once for all these tests I'm running, since I have to do it for each test. in short a beforeEach() kind of function in Rust?
